# ExpressPrinting in RDP sessions to a Windows Server, only a few printers show up

Tags: windows, delphi, printing, devexpress, rdp

This is not a question, but I didn't find a section where to put this experience to help others.

---

### Problem:

Using ExpressPrinting system components (DevExpress VCL), when connecting via RDP with the option enable sharing of user's local printers, these printers are not listed in the device selection dialog. Only printers installed on the Remote Server (if any) are available.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow is strictly a Q&A site, you should have formulated a question and self-answered it, in such a way that the Q and A together contain all this information you want to share.

Comment: Thanks for adding this - you could split this into two parts: 1) your problem as a question and then 2) mark is as answared by yourself.

Comment: Thanks boys... Andreas & R.Hoek

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

This was raised by the user ***"Luis Madaleno"*** in the official DevExpress forum, and it was the user himself who finally found the following solution:

> "...before calling TdxComponentPrinter.Preview: "

```
 if (Printer.Printers.Count <> dxPrintDevice.Printers.Count)
     then dxPrintDevice.Refresh;
```

More on the "why?" of this problem, you can find it in [the original query raised](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t232049/in-rdp-sessions-to-a-windows-server-2012-r2-only-a-few-printers-show-up) in the official forum of the product.

---

> #### Technical Note
>
> *This situation generally occurs when the configuration of the user account launches the execution of a program (.exe) when the session is connected, that is, the user "does not see" the Windows Remote Desktop and directly launches a application.
>
> The user can only interact with the printers through the dialog boxes offered by said application.-*

Finding this solution took me a long time.
That's why I share it here. I hope it is helpful to the community.
Best regards,